# trying to get the value of a random number and put it in a specific div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display random number in a specific div or grid do i need to store number first i would like some advice on how i can achieve this. for example if random number is 4 i would like that value in div 4, then if my next random number is 10 place it in div 10

browser example

[image]

```js
function lottoNumbers() {
  var lottoNums = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    if (lottoNums.indexOf(temp) == -1) {
      `enter code here`
      lottoNums.push(temp);
      document.getElementById('square' + i).innerHTML = lottoNums[i];
    } else {
      i--;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="lightblue">
  <h1>
    <center>GENERATE LOTTO NUMBERS</center>
  </h1>

  <div class="divContainer">
    <div id=square0 class=num></div>

  </div>

  </br>



  <div class="hej">
    <div id=square1 class=nums></div>
    <div id=square2 class=nums></div>
    <div id=square3 class=nums></div>
    <div id=square4 class=nums></div>
  </div>

  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>


  <div class=hei>
    <div id=square5 class=nums></div>
    <div id=square6 class=nums></div>
    <div id=square7 class=nums></div>
    <div id=square8 class=nums></div>
  </div>

  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>

  <div class="hek">
    <div id=square9 class=nums></div>
    <div id=square10 class=nums></div>
    <div id=square11 class=nums></div>
    <div id=square12 class=nums></div>
  </div>




  <center>
    <input id="btn" class="knapp" type="button" value="lotto" onClick="lottoNumbers();">
    </cennter>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your approach is correct. `<div id="square1" class="nums">` id and class requires double quotes but apart from that there is nothing wrong here.

Comment: You need to be referencing the `temp` variable, not the loop variable when specifying the `id` of the target `div`. Also, your HTML is invalid: `</br>` doesn't exist (it's `<br>`) and `<center>` as well as `bgcolor` are deprecated. You also have mismatched starting and ending tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your number wasn't being placed on the right spot as You generated the `temp` variable which is the random number, but have addressed it to variable `i` which is the iterator of the for loop. This way, if You would generate 3 random numbers, they would be placed in the divs square0, square1, square2 when they actually should be placed in the divs `'square'+temp` that correspond to the actual generated number. Please see my example:

```js
    document.getElementById ("btn").addEventListener ("click", lottoNumbers, false);
    function lottoNumbers() {
      var lottoNums = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
        lottoNums.push(temp);
          document.getElementById('square' + temp).innerHTML = lottoNums[i];
       document.getElementById('square0').innerHTML = lottoNums[i];
       
      }
    }
```

```css
    .num {
     border: 1px solid;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     margin: 2px;
    }
    .nums {
     border: 1px solid;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     margin: 2px;
     float: left;
    }
    body {
     background-color: lightblue;
    }
    .hej{
     float: left;
     width: 120px;
     height: 30px;
     clear: both;
    }
    .hei{
     float: left;
      width: 120px;
     height: 30px;
     clear: both;
    
    }
    .hek{
     float: left;
     width: 120px;
     height: 30px;
     clear: both;
    }
    .divContainer{
     float: right;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     font-size: 15px;
    }
```

```html
     <h1>
    <center>GENERATE LOTTO NUMBERS</center>
  

    </h1>
    
      <div class="divContainer">
        <div id="square0" class="num"></div>
    
      </div>
    
    
    
    
      <div class="hej">
        <div id="square1" class="nums"></div>
        <div id="square2" class="nums"></div>
        <div id="square3" class="nums"></div>
        <div id="square4" class="nums"></div>
      </div>
     <div class="hei">
        <div id="square5" class="nums"></div>
        <div id="square6" class="nums"></div>
        <div id="square7" class="nums"></div>
        <div id="square8" class="nums"></div>
      </div>
    
    
      <div class="hek">
        <div id="square9" class="nums"></div>
        <div id="square10" class="nums"></div>
        <div id="square11" class="nums"></div>
        <div id="square12" class="nums"></div>
      </div>
    
    
    
    
        <input id="btn" class="knapp" type="button" value="lotto"">
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first answer. The event handler wasn't working for me on jsfiddle, don't know why. I'll edit again

Answer (score -1):

You can just change

`document.getElementById('square' + i).innerHTML = lottoNums[i];`

to

`document.getElementById('square' + lottoNums[i]).innerHTML = lottoNums[i];`

to put each random number in the div matching that number.

Comment: Can whoever down voted my answer please leave a comment explaining what's wrong with it? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the phrasing.